# Number of elements on cart refreshes only after page refresh Angular 8

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, refresh, mean-stack

I'm working on a simple shopping MEAN stack application.
On the header component I have a cart with badge that shows number of elements on the user's cart,when I click on add to cart button (which is situated on my products component), the product is added normally but the number of elements on cart only updates when I refresh the page.
This is my header template code :

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <div class="input-group-append" *ngFor="let p of panier">

                </div>
                        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" *ngIf="isConnected" routerLink="/panier">
                            <!-- <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" *ngIf="!isConnected" routerLink="/"></a> -->
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart
                <span class="badge badge-light">{{getSize()}}</span>
            </a>
            </div>
```

This is my header component code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthentificationService } from '../authentification.service';

import { ProduitsService } from '../produits.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user;
  isConnected = false;
  private panier: [];
  size=0; 


  constructor(private AuthService : AuthentificationService,
    private produitsService: ProduitsService) { }


    setSize(quantite){
      this.size+=quantite;
    }
    getSize(){
      console.log(this.panier.length);
     return this.size;
    }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.AuthService.getUser().subscribe(data =>{


      this.AuthService.getUser().subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.user = data;
        if ( this.user ){Â this.isConnected = true;}
        else {Â this.isConnected = false;}
        console.log("est connectÃ© : " + this.isConnected );
        this.produitsService.getproduitsPanier(this.user).subscribe(data => {
         // console.log("received : " + JSON.stringify(data));
          this.panier = data;
          if (this.panier) //dans le cas oÃ¹ le panier n'est pas encore initialisÃ©
          this.size = this.panier.length; 
          console.log("produits : " + this.panier);
        });

    });



  });


  }



}
```

And this is my product component code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProduitsService } from '../produits.service';
import { AuthentificationService } from '../authentification.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {HomeComponent} from '../home/home.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-produits',
  templateUrl: './produits.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./produits.component.css']
})

export class ProduitsComponent implements OnInit {

  private produits: Object[] = new Array();
  user;
  isConnected = false;
  produitAEnvoyer = {
    "email":"",
    "img" :"",
    "nom" :"",
    "marque" : "",
    "prix" : "",
    "quantite" :""
  };

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private produitsService: ProduitsService,
    private AuthService : AuthentificationService,
    private HomeComponent : HomeComponent) {

      }

  ajouterAuPanier(img, nom, marque, prix){


    this.produitAEnvoyer.email = this.user;
    this.produitAEnvoyer.img = img;
    this.produitAEnvoyer.nom = nom;
    this.produitAEnvoyer.marque = marque;
    this.produitAEnvoyer.prix = prix;

    console.log(this.produitAEnvoyer);
    this.produitsService.ajouterAuPanier(this.produitAEnvoyer).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  updateQuantite(value){
    this.produitAEnvoyer["quantite"] = value;
    console.log("quantite :"+this.produitAEnvoyer.quantite);
  }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.produitsService.getProduits().subscribe(produits =>{

      this.produits = produits;


      for (const p of this.produits) {
        this.produits.sort();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(p));
      }
  });


  this.AuthService.getUser().subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data);
    this.user = data;
    if ( this.user ){Â this.isConnected = true;}
    else {Â this.isConnected = false;}
    console.log("est connecte : " + this.isConnected+" email :"+this.user);

});


  }

}
```

Edit 1: 
This is also my product template :

```
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">


<div class="container">


                    <br>  <b><h2 class="text-center">  Catalog of All Our Products ! </h2></b>
                    <hr>

                <br><br>


<div class="card" >
<table class="table table-hover shopping-cart-wrap">
<thead class="text-muted">
<tr>
  <th scope="col">Product</th>
  <th scope="col" width="120">Brand</th>
   <th scope="col" width="120">Price</th>
   <th scope="col" width="120">Quantity</th>
  <th scope="col" width="200" class="text-right">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let produit of produits">

    <tr>
        <td>
    <figure class="media" >
        <div class="img-wrap"><img src={{produit.img}} class="img-thumbnail img-sm"></div>
        <figcaption class="media-body">
            <h6 class="title text-truncate"> {{produit.nom}} </h6>

        </figcaption>
    </figure> 
    <td> 
        <div class="price-wrap"> 
            <var class="price"> {{produit.marque}} </var> 
        </div> <!-- brand-wrap .// -->
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="price-wrap"> 
            <var class="price">USD  {{produit.prix}} $</var> 
            <small class="text-muted">(For 1 quantity)</small> 
        </div> <!-- price-wrap .// -->
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div class="price-wrap"> 
            <input class="form-control" type="number" required (click)="updateQuantite($event.target.value)" min="1" max="20"/> 
        </div> <!-- quantity-wrap .// -->
    </td>
        <td class="text-right" > 
        <a title="" (click)= "ajouterAuPanier(produit.img, produit.nom, produit.marque, produit.prix)" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save to Wishlist" > <i class="fa fa-heart" ></i> Add to cart</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div> <!-- card.// -->

</div> 
<!--container end.//-->
```

Comment: Can you add the html page on you are add the header component and product component? Maybe you can use the Input and Output methods and the ngOnChanges method for solved a this problem

Comment: I've added the product template (on which adding product to the cart is called) on my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Service` and `Rxjs subject` can solve your problem.

When `add` or `remove` button is clicked, the header must be informed that some event occurred and updated the latest value. For that `Service` can be used as the communication channel.

Note: `@input` and `@output` can be used only if components are in the parent-child relationship. So for this case using Service is the best option.

To update the value in the header component `Observable` can be used.

header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent {
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.appService.getCount().subscribe(count => {
          this.totalItem = count
          }
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

appService

```
export class AppService {
  count = 0;
  simpleObservable = new Subject();
  simpleObservable$ = this.simpleObservable.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  addCount() {
    this.count+=1;
    this.simpleObservable.next(this.count)
  }
  removeCount() {
    if (this.count > 0) { this.count-=1 };
    this.simpleObservable.next(this.count)
  }
  getCount(){
    return this.simpleObservable$;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxsxqe)

Comment: Thank you bro, your solution is worked but there is a doubt on it, well I've added observables into my ProductService, and I've subscribed the header to getCount(), but when the add to cart action accures the element's number increases with 2 elements not 1, how can I fix this ?

Comment: could you share a StackBlitz example that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the communication between parent and child component using `@Input()`, `@Output()` and `EventEmitter` but as you already have a `ProduitService` you could use it to share data. In your case the total number of items.

Set a `BehaviorSubject` in your ProduitService:

```
  total = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  setTotalItems(value: number) {
    this.total.next(value);
  }
```

Then in your ProduitsComponent you can set the value:

```
this.produitService.setTotalItems(value);
```

For a somewhat related case see this: [How to communicate with other component in Angular 8 to Add Total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278262/how-to-communicate-with-other-component-in-angular-8-to-add-total)

And it's related Stackblitz I made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqxex9

The you can find a simple implementation of a communication between components using a shared service.